# Clone from public repository and push to private repository

Tags: github

I have cloned a public repository from github, made some modifications and now I want to push them to a private repo. The steps I took are shown below:

```
$ git clone -b dev https://github.com/public_repo
$ cd public_repo
## modify files
$ git add .
$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   ...
    modified:   ...
    modified:   ...
    ...
$ git commit -m "Now supports new features"
[dev 5f98577c] Now supports Chiplet
 68 files changed, 2855 insertions(+), 1910 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 ....
$ git remote add private https://private_domain
$ git push private dev
Username for ...
Password for ...
To https://private_domain
 ! [rejected]          dev -> dev (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://private_domain'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Note that the private repository is also on dev branch. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to error : you have different code on the private repo `dev` branch and you're trying to push some other changes without taking pull . please try to take pull before push

Comment: Same error. Pull command says `Already up to date`

Comment: you're taking pull with `git pull private dev` command. right?

Comment: No. that was only `git pull`. Now that I run `git pull private dev`, I see some conflict errors. So, the question is, how to merge them?

Comment: Yes, when you write `git pull` then it pull from origin. So now solve the conflicts and try to push . It will work. :)